# find the distribution of Z=XY

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Given two absolutely continous random variables $X$ and $Y$, I've got to determine  the distribution of $Z=XY$. 
My question is, can I assume that these two variables are independent? So that the distribution here is: $$
f_Z(z)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{|t|} f_X\left(t\right)f_Y\left(\frac{z}{t}\right)dt
$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My question is, can I assume that these two variables are independent?

You cannot without justification.   What information about the variables do you have that would allow you to do so?

> So that the distribution here is: $$
> f_Z(z)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{|t|} f_X\left(t\right)f_Y\left(\frac{z}{t}\right)\operatorname dt
> $$

If they *are* independent, yes, otherwise if you know the *joint probability density function* then :

$$
f_Z(z)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\lvert t\rvert}~f_{X,Y}\Bigl(t,\frac{z}{t}\Bigr)\operatorname dt
$$

Comment: What is $\frac{1}{|t|}$ here?

Comment: The [Jacobian determinant](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant).

Comment: Okay Sir, thanks.